# Why can't Angular find my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controller

I am getting the "Error: ng:areq" error when trying to load any view.  I have the following file structure:

```
-app/modules
    -- dashboard
       --- views/ dashboard.html
       --- controllers/ dashboard-ctrl.js
-app.js
```

I have one module that holds all my controllers called "si.modules".  I have added that as a dependency in the main app.js module like so:

```
var app = angular.module('xenon-app', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',

    'oc.lazyLoad',

    'xenon.controllers',
    'xenon.directives',
    'xenon.factory',
    'xenon.factory.si',
    'xenon.services',
    'uiSwitch',
    'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
     'si.modules',

    // Added in v1.3
    'FBAngular',

    //Added for image uploader 
    'angularFileUpload',

    //ngtags input
    'ngTagsInput',

]);
```

I have also included the controller files in my index.html like so:

```
  <script src="app/scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/modules/Dashboard/dashboard-ctrl.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `<script src="app/modules/dashboard/controllers/dashboard-ctrl.js"></script>` ?

Comment: @MiTa is probably correct. Also, the specific error would help.

Comment: @MiTa ooh i see.  I changed the path, but I'm still getting the same error.  The error says: "Error: ng:areq, Bad Argument" dashboardController is undefined

Comment: @JoshPMP you're just missing /controllers/ , take a look at your folder structure , your controller is inside 'controllers', which is inside 'dashboard'. Just a pathing issue :).

Answer (score 0):

You include :

```
<script src="app/modules/Dashboard/dashboard-ctrl.js"></script>
```

But from your project structure it should be  :

```
<script src="app/modules/dashboard/controllers/dashboard-ctrl.js"></script>
```

You were missing `controllers` directory

Comment: Ok, I've adjusted my folder path, but I'm still getting the same error.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="app/scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/Dashboard/dashboard-ctrl.js"></script>
```

Is suppose to be,

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/dashboard/controllers/dashboard-ctrl.js"></script>
```